Files freeze when searching
When I type in a search bar I get "files not responding" and must quit.
Typing nautilus in the terminal gets:
(org.gnome.Nautilus:2545879): Tracker-WARNING **: 09:35:27.184: Could not delete '.meta.isrunning': No such file or directory

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:2545879): WARNING **: 09:35:27.184: Unable to initialize tag manager: Database version is too new: got version 28, but 26 is needed
GSConnect: No translation file found for domain
Nautilus-Share-Message: 09:35:27.563: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/nautilus-gsconnect.py", line 144, in get_file_items
    def get_file_items(self, window, files):
KeyboardInterrupt
** Message: 09:37:35.821: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
Killed

On Ubuntu 22.04, I attempt to search in a file and get the message "file not responding". I might add that I updated to 24.04 which was a disaster, so I went back to 22.04 via timeshift

Please edit and add the version of Ubuntu being used. Also the exact command or steps you are using would help.

Ubuntu 22.04 I attempt to search in a file, get message "file not responding"  I might add that I updated to 24.04 which was a disaster, so went back to 22.04 via timeshift

Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you try deleting both ~/.cache/tracker and ~/.cache/tracker3 files and restart the system??

thank you. I deleted ~/.cache/tracker3 (I think) but the first the command didn't work. Maybe I did it wrong.

Do tracker3 reset -s to remove the indexing database that was upgraded with 24.04.
Update since GNOME 47:
Since tracker was renamed to localsearch, the command could be localsearch3 reset -s on other distributions or in Ubuntu the future.

thank you.  Seems to work now
